# New taxonomy vocabs being generated with blank, broken fields

Tags: 7, commerce

I have a standard Drupal 7 site with Commerce modules enabled. Enabled the `taxonomy` module and created a vocab, but when I go to manage fields, there's an odd blank field there that causes "save" to break, as well as viewing the display options. Equally, trying to edit or delete the field doesn't work as the URLs they point to are non-existent (/fields/ and /fields//delete, respectively).

I was deleting data from some commerce tables and field_data_* tables in the db in order to clear out product info, so that could be a culprit; but I don't know why it would affect field definitions, especially in taxonomy terms.

Any ideas? Thanks.

#### Manage fields page:

[image: Issue with blank field]

#### Manage display page:

[image: Manage display page]

#### Enabled modules:

```
matt@MaffBookPro:~/work/freelance/plainbear/plainbear.co.uk/www/sites$ drush pm-list | grep 'Enabled'
 Administration                       Administration menu (admin_menu)                                      Module  Enabled        7.x-3.0-rc5    
 Chaos tool suite                     Chaos tools (ctools)                                                  Module  Enabled        7.x-1.9        
 Commerce                             Cart (commerce_cart)                                                  Module  Enabled        7.x-1.11       
 Commerce                             Checkout (commerce_checkout)                                          Module  Enabled        7.x-1.11       
 Commerce                             Commerce (commerce)                                                   Module  Enabled        7.x-1.11       
 Commerce                             Commerce Multicurrency (commerce_multicurrency)                       Module  Enabled        7.x-1.3        
 Commerce                             Commerce UI (commerce_ui)                                             Module  Enabled        7.x-1.11       
 Commerce                             Customer (commerce_customer)                                          Module  Enabled        7.x-1.11       
 Commerce                             Customer UI (commerce_customer_ui)                                    Module  Enabled        7.x-1.11       
 Commerce                             Line Item (commerce_line_item)                                        Module  Enabled        7.x-1.11       
 Commerce                             Line Item UI (commerce_line_item_ui)                                  Module  Enabled        7.x-1.11       
 Commerce                             Order (commerce_order)                                                Module  Enabled        7.x-1.11       
 Commerce                             Order UI (commerce_order_ui)                                          Module  Enabled        7.x-1.11       
 Commerce                             Payment (commerce_payment)                                            Module  Enabled        7.x-1.11       
 Commerce                             Payment UI (commerce_payment_ui)                                      Module  Enabled        7.x-1.11       
 Commerce                             Price (commerce_price)                                                Module  Enabled        7.x-1.11       
 Commerce                             Product (commerce_product)                                            Module  Enabled        7.x-1.11       
 Commerce                             Product Pricing (commerce_product_pricing)                            Module  Enabled        7.x-1.11       
 Commerce                             Product Pricing UI (commerce_product_pricing_ui)                      Module  Enabled        7.x-1.11       
 Commerce                             Product Reference (commerce_product_reference)                        Module  Enabled        7.x-1.11       
 Commerce                             Product UI (commerce_product_ui)                                      Module  Enabled        7.x-1.11       
 Commerce (contrib)                   Card on File (commerce_cardonfile)                                    Module  Enabled        7.x-2.0-beta5  
 Commerce (contrib)                   Commerce Addressbook (commerce_addressbook)                           Module  Enabled        7.x-2.0-rc9    
 Commerce (contrib)                   Commerce Backoffice (commerce_backoffice)                             Module  Enabled        7.x-1.5        
 Commerce (contrib)                   Commerce Backoffice content (commerce_backoffice_content)             Module  Enabled        7.x-1.5        
 Commerce (contrib)                   Commerce Backoffice Order (commerce_backoffice_order)                 Module  Enabled        7.x-1.5        
 Commerce (contrib)                   Commerce Backoffice Product (commerce_backoffice_product)             Module  Enabled        7.x-1.5        
 Commerce (contrib)                   Commerce Billy (commerce_billy)                                       Module  Enabled        7.x-1.0        
 Commerce (contrib)                   Commerce Billy Mail (commerce_billy_mail)                             Module  Enabled        7.x-1.0-beta5  
 Commerce (contrib)                   Commerce Billy PDF (commerce_billy_pdf)                               Module  Enabled        7.x-1.0        
 Commerce (contrib)                   Commerce Checkout Progress (commerce_checkout_progress)               Module  Enabled        7.x-1.4        
 Commerce (contrib)                   Commerce Default Product Variant (commerce_default_product_variant)   Module  Enabled        7.x-1.3        
 Commerce (contrib)                   Commerce Devel (commerce_devel)                                       Module  Enabled        7.x-1.0-beta6  
 Commerce (contrib)                   Commerce Devel Generate (commerce_devel_generate)                     Module  Enabled        7.x-1.0-beta6  
 Commerce (contrib)                   Commerce Feeds (commerce_feeds)                                       Module  Enabled        7.x-1.3        
 Commerce (contrib)                   Commerce Message (commerce_message)                                   Module  Enabled        7.x-1.0-rc3    
 Commerce (contrib)                   Commerce Product Add On (commerce_pado)                               Module  Enabled        7.x-1.5        
 Commerce (contrib)                   Commerce Reorder (commerce_reorder)                                   Module  Enabled        7.x-1.1        
 Commerce (contrib)                   Commerce Search API (commerce_search_api)                             Module  Enabled        7.x-1.4        
 Commerce (PayPal)                    PayPal (commerce_paypal)                                              Module  Enabled        7.x-2.3        
 Commerce (PayPal)                    PayPal Express Checkout (commerce_paypal_ec)                          Module  Enabled        7.x-2.3        
 Commerce (shipping)                  Flat Rate (commerce_flat_rate)                                        Module  Enabled        7.x-1.0-beta2  
 Commerce (shipping)                  Shipping (commerce_shipping)                                          Module  Enabled        7.x-2.2        
 Commerce (shipping)                  Shipping UI (commerce_shipping_ui)                                    Module  Enabled        7.x-2.2        
 Commerce (Tax)                       VAT (commerce_vat)                                                    Module  Enabled        7.x-1.0-rc2    
 Commerce (Tax)                       VAT Product field (commerce_vat_field)                                Module  Enabled        7.x-1.0-rc2    
 Commerce (Tax)                       VAT Reference Field (commerce_vat_reference)                          Module  Enabled        7.x-1.0-rc2    
 Commerce - Payment                   SagePay Integration for Drupal Commerce (commerce_sagepay)            Module  Enabled        7.x-1.0        
 Commerce EU VAT                      Commerce EU VAT (commerce_eu_vat)                                     Module  Enabled        7.x-2.4        
 Commerce EU VAT                      Commerce EU VAT GB (commerce_eu_vat_gb)                               Module  Enabled        7.x-2.4        
 Core                                 Database logging (dblog)                                              Module  Enabled        7.41           
 Core                                 Field (field)                                                         Module  Enabled        7.41           
 Core                                 Field SQL storage (field_sql_storage)                                 Module  Enabled        7.41           
 Core                                 Field UI (field_ui)                                                   Module  Enabled        7.41           
 Core                                 File (file)                                                           Module  Enabled        7.41           
 Core                                 Filter (filter)                                                       Module  Enabled        7.41           
 Core                                 Image (image)                                                         Module  Enabled        7.41           
 Core                                 List (list)                                                           Module  Enabled        7.41           
 Core                                 Node (node)                                                           Module  Enabled        7.41           
 Core                                 Options (options)                                                     Module  Enabled        7.41           
 Core                                 System (system)                                                       Module  Enabled        7.41           
 Core                                 Taxonomy (taxonomy)                                                   Module  Enabled        7.41           
 Core                                 Text (text)                                                           Module  Enabled        7.41           
 Core                                 Update manager (update)                                               Module  Enabled        7.41           
 Core                                 User (user)                                                           Module  Enabled        7.41           
 Date/Time                            Date (date)                                                           Module  Enabled        7.x-2.9        
 Date/Time                            Date API (date_api)                                                   Module  Enabled        7.x-2.9        
 Date/Time                            Date Popup (date_popup)                                               Module  Enabled        7.x-2.9        
 Date/Time                            Date Views (date_views)                                               Module  Enabled        7.x-2.9        
 Development                          Devel (devel)                                                         Module  Enabled        7.x-1.5        
 Development                          Devel generate (devel_generate)                                       Module  Enabled        7.x-1.5        
 Features                             Commerce Features (commerce_features)                                 Module  Enabled        7.x-1.1        
 Features                             Features (features)                                                   Module  Enabled        7.x-2.7        
 Features                             ServicesExample (servicesexample)                                     Module  Enabled                       
 Feeds                                Feeds (feeds)                                                         Module  Enabled        7.x-2.0-beta1  
 Fields                               Address Field (addressfield)                                          Module  Enabled        7.x-1.2        
 Fields                               Entity Reference (entityreference)                                    Module  Enabled        7.x-1.1        
 Message                              Message (message)                                                     Module  Enabled        7.x-1.10       
 Message                              Message notify (message_notify)                                       Module  Enabled        7.x-2.5        
 OAuth                                OAuth (oauth_common)                                                  Module  Enabled        7.x-3.2        
 OAuth                                OAuth Provider UI (oauth_common_providerui)                           Module  Enabled        7.x-3.2        
 Other                                CORS (cors)                                                           Module  Enabled        7.x-1.3        
 Other                                Entity API (entity)                                                   Module  Enabled        7.x-1.6        
 Other                                Entity tokens (entity_token)                                          Module  Enabled        7.x-1.6        
 Other                                Job Scheduler (job_scheduler)                                         Module  Enabled        7.x-2.0-alpha3 
 Other                                Libraries (libraries)                                                 Module  Enabled        7.x-2.2        
 Other                                Multiple Node Add (multi_node_add)                                    Module  Enabled        7.x-1.0-beta4  
 Other                                Token (token)                                                         Module  Enabled        7.x-1.6        
 Other                                Weight (weight)                                                       Module  Enabled        7.x-2.5        
 Performance and scalability          Boost (boost)                                                         Module  Enabled        7.x-1.0        
 Rules                                Rules (rules)                                                         Module  Enabled        7.x-2.9        
 Rules                                Rules UI (rules_admin)                                                Module  Enabled        7.x-2.9        
 Search                               Search API (search_api)                                               Module  Enabled        7.x-1.16       
 Search                               Solr search (search_api_solr)                                         Module  Enabled        7.x-1.9        
 Services                             Commerce Services (commerce_services)                                 Module  Enabled        7.x-1.x-dev    
 Services                             Plain Bear Commerce Services (pb_commerce_services)                   Module  Enabled                       
 Services                             Services (services)                                                   Module  Enabled        7.x-3.12       
 Services                             Services Views (services_views)                                       Module  Enabled        7.x-1.1        
 Services - authentication            OAuth Authentication (services_oauth)                                 Module  Enabled        7.x-3.12       
 Services - servers                   REST Server (rest_server)                                             Module  Enabled        7.x-3.12       
 Views                                Eva (eva)                                                             Module  Enabled        7.x-1.2        
 Views                                Views (views)                                                         Module  Enabled        7.x-3.11       
 Views                                Views Bulk Operations (views_bulk_operations)                         Module  Enabled        7.x-3.3        
 Views                                Views megarow (views_megarow)                                         Module  Enabled        7.x-1.5        
 Core                                 Bartik (bartik)                                                       Theme   Enabled        7.41           
 Core                                 Seven (seven)                                                         Theme   Enabled        7.41
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[The sound of tumbleweed gently rolling past]`

Well, cheers for all the help guys ;)

Finally managed to fix it myself. The culprit was `commerce_services`, fixed with [this patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/2024813-4-bundle-key.patch) and documented [in this drupal.org thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/2024813#comment-7718289).